# SQL Alchemy ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column

Tags: python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, db2

im coding on a migrationtool for bringing DDL and raw-data from a DB2 database to a mssql database. When i will reflect my database by SQL Alchemy ORM, i get the fellowing error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2877, in __init__
    "ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column "
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column references are not supported.
```

I am looking for hours on the Internet for a solution but I'm helpless. It would be great if you could help me. Here is the code:
(The exception is throughn in the last line of my code)

```
    elif type == "db2":
        self.engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(user,
                                                                           password,
                                                                           server,
                                                                           port,
                                                                           dbname),
                                    echo=log)
    else:
        print(u"Nicht unterstützte Quelldatenbank!")
        SystemExit()
    # check if engine is working
    assert isinstance(self.engine.connect, object)
    # reflect the tables
    self.Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
```

Here is the ddl:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVi7y.png)

**UPDATE:
I saw that one of the "tables" is an alias table. Maybe that helps.**

Thanks in advance from germany
Jassin

Comment: Can you show the foreign-key DDL that triggers this?  from the sqlalchemy source it reads " if len(set(columns)) != len(refcolumns):
            if len(set(columns)) != len(columns):
                # e.g. FOREIGN KEY (a, a) REFERENCES r (b, c)
                raise exc.ArgumentError(
                    "ForeignKeyConstraint with duplicate source column "
                    "references are not supported.""

Comment: Hi, here is the fkey DLL. I hope this is what u mean. Thanks in advance.
https://ibb.co/ni2iia

Comment: The diagram does not help me, what I meant was for you to get the actual data-definition-language source-code for the foreign-keys in your database (you can use db2look for this purpose) in plain text format. The schema.py source code suggests that the FK should be simple, so check which objects (if any) have composite FKs or composite PKs . You may have additional configuration to do.

Comment: `assert isinstance(self.engine.connect, object)` is the most ridiculous thing I've seen today...